# How do I come up with a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the matrix that rotates by (pi/4) about an axis that is parallel to Y and passing through the point (9, 0, 0)?

Does anyone knows what this question means?

Comment: This rotation seems to move the origin. If this correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Background**:  Locations (positions) are represented by "augmented" vectors:  $(x,y,z, 1)^t$, and you operate on them with Affine transformation matrices to get the output $(X,Y,Z,1)^t$.

The matrix for the translation by $(\Delta X, \Delta Y, \Delta Z)^t$ is of the form:

$${\bf M}_{trans} = \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \Delta X \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \Delta Y \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta Z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}
\right)$$

(To check you understand this, compute ${\bf M}_{trans} (x, y, z, 1)^t$ by hand.  It takes just a few seconds to do that.)

**Solution**:  The Affine matrix for a rotation by $\theta$ about a three-dimensional vector ${\bf v}$ is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: The way I read the question, I think we want to operate on $\Bbb R^3$, so with your augmentation we are in a hyperplane of $\Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, such a rotation can be decomposed into a rotation into the $xOz$ plane and the identity on $y$-axis.

[image]

1. A 2D Rotation $R$ with angle $+\tfrac{\pi}{4}$  into the $x0z$ plane (in fact it is a rotation on the projection on $x0z$: see figures):

Let $a:=\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\cos\tfrac{\pi}{4}=\sin\tfrac{\pi}{4}$.

$$\underbrace{\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
x'-9 \\
z'-0 
\end{array}
\right)}_{\vec{CM'_1}}=\underbrace{\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
a & -a \\
a & a 
\end{array}
\right)}_R\underbrace{\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
x-9 \\
z-0 
\end{array}
\right)}_{\vec{CM_1}}\iff \begin{cases}x'&=&ax-az-9a+9\\z'&=&ax+az-9a\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

where the rotation matrix $R$ comes from the classical form $\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
\end{array}
\right)$.

2. "statu quo" in the $y$ direction:

$$y'=y.\tag{2}$$

The final answer is the affine transformation obtained by grouping (1) and (2):

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{r}
x'\\
y'\\
z' 
\end{array}
\right)=\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
a & \ \ 0 & -a \\
0 & \ \ 1 & 0  \\
a & \ \ 0 & a 
\end{array}
\right)\left( 
\begin{array}{r}
x\\
y\\
z 
\end{array}
\right)+\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
-9a+9\\
0\\
-9a 
\end{array}
\right) \ \ \text{with} \ \ a=\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

Comment: Is my answer understandable ? You see that you have to add to the matrix operation a certain constant vector (this is the difference between a purely linear $X'=AX$ and an affine transformation $X'=AX+B$ as is the case here).